# Display abbreviated form of a function name?

Tags: symbols

I've seen videos where someone an elisp function call like

```
(so-and-so/do-stuff)
```

But were able to shorted the displayed function name to something like

```
(so/do-stuff)
```

How do they do that? I'd like to use it in my init.el so I can display this

```
(i/do-stuff)
```

rather than this

```
(ivan/do-stuff)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by using Malabarba's [Nameless](https://github.com/Malabarba/nameless) package, it is available from both GNU ELPA and MELPA. You probably want to customize the `nameless-global-aliases` and `nameless-prefix` user options. Something like:

```
(setq nameless-global-aliases '(("i" . "ivan")))
(setq nameless-prefix "/")
```

and open your init.el then `M-x nameless-mode`.